# Mock AWS services for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-web-services

I am looking for ways to test AWS services without actually using AWS cloud. Python is the language of choice.

Using some mock components which will let me test my code which uses AWS S3, Redshift, Lambda, Dynamodb etc

So far I have found,

1. [Localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) (This supports most of the AWS services)
2. [Minio](https://www.minio.io/) - This one supports S3 and Lambda
3. [s3rver](https://github.com/jamhall/s3rver) - supports only AWS S3

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using boto3 to access the AWS resources? If so, it sounds like moto is perfect for what you need https://github.com/spulec/moto

Comment: This looks promising. Will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Commandeer](https://getcommandeer.com) to view the complete localstack (as well as AWS) environment from a desktop app.[image]